# Java client SocketTimeoutException failed to connect to ip

Tags: java, c#, android, sockets

I am trying to connect my java client made in android studio to a c# host, but I always get this exception.
here is the client code:

```
{
 soc=new Socket();
            soc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(ip,port),1000);
            DataOutputStream outstream =new DataOutputStream(soc.getOutputStream());
            byte[] buffer;
            buffer = this.mesaj.getBytes("UTF-8");
            outstream.write(buffer);
            outstream.flush();
            outstream.close();
}
```

here is the host:

```
Socket main_soc = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    IPEndPoint ip_target = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(gen_info.get_ip()), gen_info.get_port());
                ascultator.Bind(ip_target);
                ascultator.Listen(150);
                while (true)
                {
                    Socket transceiver = ascultator.Accept();
                    if(transceiver.Connected)
                    {
                        Thread interpretation_thread = new Thread(() => interpret_signal(transceiver));
                        interpretation_thread.Start();
                    }
                }
```

I don't know why this is happening. The host works, when I start it the port appear to be listening in cmd and a c# client on the pc connects with no problem. I used all the ip addresses I found with IP config but none works. I am debugging with an android device(I used 2 actually but none works).

Comment: On your host, are you listening on IPv4 or only IPv6? Is there a firewall active?

Comment: @Fildor IPv4 (AddressFamily.Internetwork). I turned off the windows firewall and is the same thing.